# How to silently install newer versions of KDiff3?

Tags: windows, installation, kdiff3

Kdiff3 is a beloved 3-way merge tool that I use for decades to develop code. I want to make it available to other users of my company, but I can't find how to silently install it from the command line.

Newest version that I found is in: https://download.kde.org/stable/kdiff3/kdiff3-1.9.6-windows-64-cl.exe

If I run the executable, it opens a install wizard. I want to be able to pass a command line option to silently install it in a specific directory, but I can't find any documentation about it. No GUI window must be open, but it may print messages in the terminal. I believe KDE tools for windows must have some standard install options, but I can't find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://invent.kde.org/sdk/kdiff3/-/blob/master/INSTALL the installer is NSIS based so

- Silent install: `"kdiff3-1.9.6-windows-64-cl.exe" /S`
- Force directory: `"kdiff3-1.9.6-windows-64-cl.exe" /S /D=c:\programs\kdiff`